# Create separate column from one row based on values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named Source which has 2 values "1" and "2".
I want to display it in 2 columns like Source_1 which will display just value "1" and Source_2 which will display value "2".
I am not sure how do I achieve it given the query that I have:

```
    Select 
    b.[path],
    count(*) as "No of Calls",
    count(a.Source) as "Source_1 calls",
    count(a.Source) as "Source_2 calls",
    a.TimeDataRetrieval as "DB Retrieval time",
    a.TimeProcessing as "Processing time",
    a.TimeRendering as "Rendering Time"

    FROM LogStorage a inner join Catalog b on a.[ReportID] = b.[ItemID]

    where b.[path] = ('/../some_path')  and a.[Source]=2
    group by b.[path]
```

Here's where I am stuck. What should I do in the where clause, because I can't have a.[Source]=1 and 2

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
Select 
b.[path],
count(*) as "No of Calls",
count(case when a.Source=1 then 1 end) as "Source_1 calls",
count(case when a.Source=2 then 1 end) as "Source_2 calls",
a.TimeDataRetrieval as "DB Retrieval time",
a.TimeProcessing as "Processing time",
a.TimeRendering as "Rendering Time"
FROM LogStorage a inner join Catalog b on a.[ReportID] = b.[ItemID]

where b.[path] = ('/../some_path')  and a.[Source]=2
group by b.[path]
```

or simply

```
sum(a.Source=1) as "Source_1 calls",
sum(a.Source=2) as "Source_2 calls",
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Didn't think about it.